# How to auto-save buffers when Emacs loses focus?

Tags: buffers, saving

I recently had a Sublime Text user try out Emacs for a while, and he was interested in getting the same auto-save behavior in Emacs.

Basically, he wanted **all buffers to be saved whenever the frame lost focus** (really saved, not just backed-up). This includes when switching windows to a completely different application.

I could not find any event that was triggered when switching to a different application. Is there such an event or is there another way to achieve the same behavior?

Note a time based solution was not satisfactory, and neither was the default auto backup behavior. He specifically wanted the buffers to be saved (as in `save-buffer`) for all files.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately, this exact behavior isn't possible in Emacs <= 24.3, but you can save on window/buffer change using `defadvice` (as detailed [on bbatsov's blog](http://batsov.com/articles/2012/03/08/emacs-tip-number-5-save-buffers-automatically-on-buffer-or-window-switch/)):

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (before save-buffer-now activate)
  (when (and buffer-file-name (buffer-modified-p)) (save-buffer)))
(defadvice other-window (before other-window-now activate)
  (when (and buffer-file-name (buffer-modified-p)) (save-buffer)))
```

In Emacs 24.4, you will also be able to save on frame focus loss thanks to the new [focus hooks](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/03/22/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-focus-hooks/): `(add-hook 'focus-out-hook 'save-buffer)` (to save the active buffer) or `(add-hook 'focus-out-hook (lambda () (save-some-buffers t)))` (to save all open buffers).

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the `defadvice` version, in case the blog post goes down or something? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution on saves the currently visible buffer, not *all* buffers.

Comment: @b4hand: Sorry, didn't realize that's what you wanted. Answer updated.

Comment: @shosti By the way, thanks for finding that link to bbatsov's blog for me. I had actually found that solution before, but couldn't find it again. I was going to include that as one of the non-working solutions in my question.

Comment: I like doing it this way to avoid trashing the minibuffer (pardon the formatting): 
```(add-hook 'focus-out-hook
          (lambda () (flet ((message
                             (format &rest args) nil))
                       (save-some-buffers t))))
```

Answer (score 6):

There is [`focus-autosave-mode`](https://github.com/vifon/focus-autosave-mode.el) now. It's available via MELPA. Why not give it a chance to do the hacking for you‽

Comment: Hi, How it work? I've install it but it don't seems to work.

Comment: @AsmeJust, I don't use right now, try to ask on its issue tracker here: https://github.com/vifon/focus-autosave-mode.el/issues

Comment: Do you currently use an alternative or somethng like that?

Comment: No, I don't use anything like that right now.

Comment: But you still use Emacs, right?

Comment: Yes, but I save manually ;-)

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/Vifon/focus-autosave-mode.el/issues/4); you must use `M-x focus-autosave-mode` for now.

Answer (score 4):

```
(add-to-list 'focus-out-hook (lambda () (save-some-buffers t nil)))
```

This will save all unsaved buffers visiting file, on emacs 24.4

Comment: Don't use `add-to-list` on a hook, use `add-hook`. shosti's answer already contains the correct form of this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

For wanderers who stumble on this, I use this form:

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))
;; [...]
(add-hook 'focus-out-hook
  (lambda ()
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'format))
      (save-some-buffers t))))
```

The use of `cl-letf` keeps the annoying `(No files need saving)` messages from clogging your echo area.