# Save file when switching buffers

Tags: auto-save

How can I get emacs to save the buffer automatically every time I switch to another buffer?

(This is similar to this question, where the buffer is [saved automatically when Emacs loses focus](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-auto-save-buffers-when-emacs-loses-focus).)

Comment: The `defadvice` lines in accepted answer on the thread to which you linked does what you're asking to do.  However, I should point out that it's probably a very dangerous thing to have Emacs save your stuff automatically -- that's what `auto-save` is for, and it doesn't overwrite your files without your explicit permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'm using:

```
(defun ora-save-and-switch-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (when (and (buffer-file-name)
             (not (bound-and-true-p archive-subfile-mode)))
    (save-buffer))
  (ido-switch-buffer))
```